# Configure Webpack Loaders For a Shared Folder?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webpack

Help appreciated!

My question is how do I get webpack to compile assets from a shared folder into the appropriate content script?

I have a Chrome Extension using react-redux-chrome.  Their file structure is:

```
-build
-content
-event
-popup
package.json
gulpfile.babel.js
manifest.json
```

The gulp file watches for changes and compiles the appropriate javascript, manifest, and html files into build.

Content, event, and popup all have their own webpack configs.

```
// content/webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  entry: [
    './content/src/scripts/index.js'
  ],

  output: {
    filename: 'content.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../', 'build'),
    publicPath: '/'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.json'],
    modulesDirectories: ['node_modules'],
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
      },
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
    ]
  }
};
```

My extension has two content scripts, so my folders look like this...

```
-build
-content1
-content2
-shared
-event
-popup
package.json
gulpfile.babel.js
manifest.json
```

Everything works fine until I try to import a React module from the shared folder.  The shared folder does not have a webpack config.  I get the error:  Unexpected token. You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

How do I get webpack to compile assets from the shared folder into the appropriate content script?  I tried an alias, but it did not work.

```
alias: {
  shared: path.normalize('../../../../../../shared')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a brain fart... just needed to make a new loader for the directory.  In the content1/webpack.config.js and content2/webpack.config.js files...

```
  {
    test: /\.(jsx|js)?$/,
    loader: 'babel',
    exclude: /(node_modules)/,
    include: path.join(__dirname, '../shared'),
    query: {
      presets: ['es2015', 'react']
    }
  },
```